# Smooth continuous movement

Tags: key, smoothing, continuous

I made a little game with pygame and allthough it looks fine to me, there's one thing I would like to improve: I want the little white square to keep moving when a key is pressed an stops moving when the key is not pressed anymore.

How can I have continious movement when arrow key (DOWN, UP, LEFT orRIGHT) is pressed ?

This is my Code so far:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Setup
width,height = 500,500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

# Colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
LGREY = (100,100,100)
DGREY = (50,50,50)

# Variables
x = y = 50

# Functions
def draw_box():
    global x,y
    if x > 425:
        x = 50
    if x <50:
        x = 425    
    if y > 425:
        y = 50
    if y < 50:
        y = 425    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect(x+1,y+1,24,24),2)

def draw_grid():
    for i in range (1,16):
        pygame.draw.line(screen,DGREY,(50+i*25,50),(50+i*25,450),1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen,DGREY,(50,50+i*25),(450,50+i*25),1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect(50,50,25*16,25*16),1)

def main():
    global x, y
    
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                   y += 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y -= 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x += 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  
                    x -= 25
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_UP):
                    y +=  0
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    x +=  0                
          
            screen.fill(LGREY)
            draw_grid()
            draw_box()
    
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(50)
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the x and y values ONLY get modified at the point when a key is pressed down, so you would have to keep pressing the keys.

You would need a way to save the state in a change_x and change_y variable, for example, and slow down the tick rate.

In the example code below, I added these two new variables and slowed down the game.  Now when a key is pressed, the state changes for change x or y, and an update function applies the update to the x and y positions.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Setup
width,height = 500,500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

# Colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
LGREY = (100,100,100)
DGREY = (50,50,50)

# Variables
x = y = 50
change_x = 0
change_y = 0


# Functions
def draw_box():
    global x,y
    if x > 425:
        x = 50
    if x <50:
        x = 425    
    if y > 425:
        y = 50
    if y < 50:
        y = 425    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect(x+1,y+1,24,24),2)

def draw_grid():
    for i in range (1,16):
        pygame.draw.line(screen,DGREY,(50+i*25,50),(50+i*25,450),1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen,DGREY,(50,50+i*25),(450,50+i*25),1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect(50,50,25*16,25*16),1)

def update_pos():
    global x, y, change_x, change_y
    x += change_x
    y += change_y

def main():
    global x, y, change_x, change_y
    
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while running:
        # event processing stage
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                   change_y = 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    change_y = -25
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    change_x = 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  
                    change_x =- 25
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_UP):
                    change_y =  0
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    change_x =  0
        # update stage
        update_pos()
        
        # draw stage
        screen.fill(LGREY)
        draw_grid()
        draw_box()
    
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if possible it would be preferable to avoid global variables.
I found the following site very helpful when I was learning pygame, and here is an example of code from that site:

```
"""
Sample Python/Pygame Programs
Simpson College Computer Science
http://programarcadegames.com/
http://simpson.edu/computer-science/
"""
 
import pygame
 
# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
 
 
def draw_stick_figure(screen, x, y):
    # Head
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)
 
    # Legs
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)
 
    # Body
    pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)
 
    # Arms
    pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)
 
# Setup
pygame.init()
 
# Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
size = [700, 500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
 
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
 
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
 
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
# Hide the mouse cursor
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
 
# Speed in pixels per frame
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
 
# Current position
x_coord = 10
y_coord = 10
 
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            # User pressed down on a key
 
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Figure out if it was an arrow key. If so
            # adjust speed.
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 3
 
        # User let up on a key
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # If it is an arrow key, reset vector back to zero
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0
 
    # --- Game Logic
 
    # Move the object according to the speed vector.
    x_coord = x_coord + x_speed
    y_coord = y_coord + y_speed
 
    # --- Drawing Code
 
    # First, clear the screen to WHITE. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)
 
    draw_stick_figure(screen, x_coord, y_coord)
 
 
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
 
    # Limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)
 
# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```